# Find lines from a file which are not present in another file

Tags: unix, text-files

I have two files (let's say `a.txt` and `b.txt`), both of which has a list of names. I have already run `sort` on both the files.

Now I want to find lines from `a.txt` which are not present in `b.txt`.

(I spent lot of time to find the answer for this question, so documenting it for future reference)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

The command you have to use is not `diff` but `comm`

```
/usr/bin/comm -23 a.txt b.txt
```

By default, `comm` outputs 3 columns: *left-only*, *right-only*, *both*. The `-1`, `-2` and `-3` switches suppress these columns.

So, `-23` hides the *right-only* and *both* columns, showing the lines that appear only in the first (left) file.

If you want to find lines that appear in both, you can use `-12`, which hides the *left-only* and *right-only* columns, leaving you with just the *both* column.

Comment: I will add that this works only if both files are sorted. (I know the OP mentioned he sorted the files, but many people, me included, read the question title and then jump to the answers)

Comment: @user247866: Fortunately comm is kind enough to tell you if they are not sorted :)

Answer (score 46):

The simple answer did not work for me because I didn't realize `comm` matches line for line, so duplicate lines in one file will be printed as not-existing in the other. For example, if file1 contained:

```
Alex
Bill
Fred
```

And file2 contained:

```
Alex
Bill
Bill
Bill
Fred
```

Then `comm -13 file1 file2` would output:

```
Bill
Bill
```

In my case, I wanted to know only that every string in file2 existed in file1, regardless of how many times that line occurred in each file.

**Solution 1:** use the `-u` (unique) flag to `sort`:

`comm -13 <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)`

**Solution 2:** (the first "working" answer I found) from [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68358/):

`fgrep -v -f file1 file2`

Note that if file2 contains duplicate lines that don't exist at all in file1, `fgrep` will output each of the duplicate lines. Also note that my totally non-scientific tests on a single laptop for a single (fairly large) dataset showed Solution 1 (using `comm`) to be almost 5 times faster than Solution 2 (using `fgrep`).

Comment: I had my files sorted and passed through uniq. Anyways thanks for the other solutions.

Comment: The `fgrep` version will be very slow, if you have tens of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 20):

I am not sure why it has been said `diff` should not be used. I would use it to compare the two files and then output only lines that are in the left file but not in right one. Such lines are flagged by diff with `<` so it suffices to grep that symbol at the beginning of the line

```
diff a.txt b.txt  | grep \^\<
```

Comment: You can use `diff --new-line-format= --unchanged-line-format= a.txt b.txt` to suppress the printing of new and unchanged lines.

Comment: diff worked fine for me. I am on win10, no comm installed.

Answer (score 16):

In the case the files wouldn't be sorted yet, you can use:

```
comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

Comment: This allocated like 15GB of memory for me for a couple files each < 300 MB...