# grep -v -f not working

Tags: linux, bash, grep

So I am trying to use

```
grep -v -f A.txt  B.txt
```

to display lines NOT included in file A but present in file B. When I

```
grep -f A.txt B.txt
```

everything works fine I receive output with correct lines highlighted, but when I use

```
grep -v -f A.txt B.txt
```

nothing is outputted in spite of the fact that not all lines match patterns. Does anyone knows why? I am interested in seeing lines NOT present in file A.

Note: I am including just a sample of original file but it includes all troublesome lines.

file B.txt contents:

```
/lgi/tch/4337984048.html
/mnh/tch/4337954734.html
/fct/tch/4337745272.html
/brk/tch/4337711890.html
/mnh/tch/4337530587.html
/mnh/tch/4337480118.html
/mnh/tch/4337393833.html
/wch/tch/4337280071.html
/wch/tch/4337105236.html
/brk/tch/4337068170.html
```

file A.txt contents:

```
/mnh/tch/4337480118.html
/mnh/tch/4337393833.html
/wch/tch/4337280071.html
/wch/tch/4337105236.html
/brk/tch/4337068170.html
```

Comment: My guess is that your `A.txt` contains a blank line (probably at the end).  That will cause the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: see if your `bin` dir has `fgrep`, then use then use `fgrep -v -f ...`. OR, per my linux man page, `grep -F -v -f ...` should work. Good luck.

Comment: try comm

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473090/find-lines-from-a-file-which-are-not-present-in-another-file

Comment: Wow actually all of you gave me an answer that works. Thank you everyone.