# Show lines in unsorted file1 that do not exist in file2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 text files, *file1* and *file2*. I need to output those lines in *file1* that do not exist in *file2*.

The lines in both files are not in the same order and there are additional lines in *file2*, which are irrelevant.

For example:

```
$ grep testme file1
chmod -f 644 /root/testme
chown -h root:root /root/testme

$ grep testme file2
chmod -f 777 /root/testme
chown -h dude:dude /root/testme
```

The above `grep` is an example of 2 lines in *file1* that are different, or as such do not exist in *file2*. Both files are about 5 MB.

Using the following procedure in Linux Bash (RHEL 7)

```
while read -r line; do
 [ "$(\grep "^$line\$" file2 )" ] || echo $line
done < file1
```

displays...

```
chmod -f 644 /root/testme
chown -h root:root /root/testme
grep: Unmatched [ or [^`
```

... and won't finish. It also takes a very long time.

I tried another approach, which is very fast, but only prints 1 of the 2 lines:

```
$ fgrep -v -f file2 file1
chmod -f 644 /root/testme
$
```

Why is it only showing 1 line?

The 2 lines are somewhere in the middle of the file, terminated by a CR.

Any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: [Get lines of file1 which are not in file2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19201029/3776858)

Comment: please refer the following thread for the above query:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473090/find-lines-from-a-file-which-are-not-present-in-another-file.

Comment: Since the input files need to be sorted, I was wondering if the absolut position of lines matter. Also the output will be sorted, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You should incorporate this last comment to the question.. check my update

Comment: Why? The problem of sorting applies to comm, but not grep or fgrep. It's comm that requires sorting and which introduces the additional concern. It's not a requirement for me not to have unsorted output, but a preference, considering how comm sorts the output. Anyway, as far as I'm concerned, the problem seems to be solved by simply using -x as outlined. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for the help and suggestion to use comm, but meanwhile I found the answer using `grep`. I rather prefer `grep`, since it's much faster than `comm` and also does not require the input to be sorted.

```
$ fgrep -v -x -f file2 file1
chmod -f 644 /root/testme
chown -h root:root /root/testme
```

The solution is simply to add `-x`:

> -x  Select only those matches that exactly  match  the  whole  line

Answer (score 0):

[`combine`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) can also do this:

```
combine <(seq 5 10) not <(seq 1 2 20)
6
8
10
```